# What is IP address '::1'?

Tags: c#, ip, system.net

I was playing with sockets on local machine with no network connection. See below:

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Any; // doesn't work
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("::1"); // works
```

So what is exactly `::1` IP address ? Is it the default available IP address or it's the loopback address ? what happens to above code (working line) on a machine with dedicated IP address and network connection ?

EDIT:

exact code is used to bind a specific IP address to socket. Here it is:

```
ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
sp.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(Bind);
// here's the bind delegate:
private IPEndPoint Bind(ServicePoint sp, IPEndPoint ep, int retryCount)
{
   return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("::1"), 0);
}
```

Comment: `IPAddress.Any` is `::0`,   You should use `IPAddress.Loopback` for local (loopback) connection.

Comment: I think this should have been posted on SuperUser.com

Comment: I'm assuming the part that says `IPAddress.Pars` is really `IPAddress.Parse`, correct?

Comment: [Reverse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189084/what-is-ipv6-for-localhost-and-0-0-0-0?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 214, accepted):

`::1` is the loopback address in IPv6.  Think of it as the IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: at above example `IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")` doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: @Xaqron - that sounds more like a superuser question, because it probably means something is broken with your IPv4 TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Xaqron, maybe a firewall is blocking v4 but not v6 traffic?

Comment: I use `Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition 64-bit` and no third-party firewall installed. I'm wondering why I cannot bind `127.0.0.1` to my socket while `::1` is available.

Comment: @Xaqron, can you show us your code that you are trying to use?  You say "works" and "doesn't work" but that isn't helpful to us.

Answer (score 31):

Just to add little more info to it, in IPv6 loopback address is represented as 127 zeroes followed by a 1 i.e (0000... 127 times..1). 
It's representation should have been like this -> **0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001** but we have some short form representation for this. If there are all zeroes in a single block you can replace it by single 0. So it becomes -> **0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0001**.
Again we can see that we have runs of zeroes, they can be eliminated and we get 
-> **::0001** -> **::1** .

Comment: (to be clear, the "127 zeroes" here are in binary, not hexadecimal)

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that:
`::1` is the compressed format of IPV6 loopback address `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. It is the equivalent of the IPV4 address `127.0. 0.1`