# HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress is null

Tags: c#, ip-address

1. In my Dev Machine `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` is null.
   Why? how can I turn it on?
2. How can I get list of Ips in case of a proxy client?

WCF Service with ASP.net 4 window7.

Thanks

Comment: I never get an empty/null, but Cassini returns a "::1" now for whatever reason.

Comment: @DoozerBlake the ::1 is IPv6's version of 127.0.0.1. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4611421/84395

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to avoid this problem you can parse the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR for the last entery IP.

```
ip=Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
{
   string[] ipRange = ip.Split(',');
   int le = ipRange.Length - 1;
   string trueIP = ipRange[le];
}
else
{
   ip=Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Just a note about `Viral Sarvaiya`'s answer. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) and [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html) the X-Forwarded-For header has the following format: > X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2 This means you should be using the first string in `ipRange`, not the last.