# Why do I always get the same IP when getting Request.UserHostAddress in WebAPI custom action filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I've created a Web API custom action filter to log incoming calls. I'm trying to get the caller's IP address and everything I've found says to use `Request.UserHostAddress`. The problem is that no matter where the call is coming from, the IP is the same.

Here's the code for my action filter:

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var name = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        // Get the sender address
        var caller = ((HttpContextWrapper)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;

        // Log the call
        SystemBL.InsertSiteLog("WebAPI:" + name, "From:" + caller);
    }
}
```

I've also tried with:

```
var caller = ((HttpContextWrapper)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
```

but the result was the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer here: [HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674731/httpcontext-current-request-userhostaddress-is-null).

Basically, I needed to sort out the forwarding. The final code is:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var name = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        // Get the sender address
        var myRequest = ((HttpContextWrapper)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request;
        var ip = myRequest.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        {
            string[] ipRange = ip.Split(',');
            int le = ipRange.Length - 1;
            string trueIP = ipRange[le];
        }
        else
        {
            ip = myRequest.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }

        // Log the call
        SystemBL.InsertSiteLog("WebAPI:" + name, "From:" + ip);
    }
```

Thanks everyone. I'll mark it as the answer in 2 days when it lets me.

Comment: Is it better to use the HttpActionContext parameter like here and receiving the IP or the better solution is to use static method which uses HttpContext like here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address) I'm not sure what approach shall I chose.

Comment: It's been a while since I did this but I think it depends on where you're using it. In my case I was doing it in a filter attribute which doesn't have access to the current context from HttpContext. If you are doing it in a regular MVC action then I would say use the HttpContext as it seems a bit cleaner. Just don't forget to do the address parsing and use the last ip in the list.

Comment: You have a bug there, trueIp-variable is never used. Maybe you wanted to assign it to the ip-variable?