# The ipaddress string is returning ::1. How can i get the full ipadrress of the user testing from localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve the ip address of the user who has logged in using c#.

I have written the following code

```
  var ipaddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

but the `ipaddress` contains `::1`. How can i get the full address. I am just only testing the code in the localhost. I have iis7 installed.

Comment: I believe ::1 is the same thing as local host, which is 127.0.0.0 if I remember correctly.

Comment: See this answer - [What is IP address '::1'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4611421/745969)

Comment: the IP adress is ok. it is same as 127.0.0.0 localhost

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611418/what-is-ip-address-1

Comment: Have a look at [How to get my own IP address in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1069103/622391) too.

Answer (score 2):

`::1` according to the specs is actually a valid address pointing to loopback.
if you want to get the computers public ip address you'll have to use a domain name (with a DNS pointing back to the your local computer) or in the url use your public ip in place of `localhost`

### edit

your code is good (nothing to change there) however if you want to get your public ip addres (not ::1 or 127.0.0.1) you'll have to make the http call from the other interface (which means it will have to go out translate the DNS into a ip and query back). you won't be able to do that offline.

i hope this helps, sorry i can't be any clearer. this is more of a networking issue then programming.

Comment: I didn't get you can you be more specific. sorry i am newbie to c#