# Get Client Ip while submit a form. (ASP.net C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to get the client ip when the user submit a form in my site.
I try to use that command: `Request.UserHostAddress`

but I get instead of the ip: `::1`

What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: This is the UserHostaddress, assuming you are running your project locally.

Comment: thanks! it's work on the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're testing locally. `::1` is the IPv6 equivalent to `127.0.0.1`.

[What is IP address '::1'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611418/what-is-ip-address-1)

Answer (score 2):

`::1` is the same as `localhost`

in ASP.NET you can do this to get the user IP Address

```
public static string GetUserIpAddress()
{
    string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if (ip == "::1") ip = "127.0.0.1"; // localhost
    }
    return ip;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use REMOTE_ADDR, but it might not work if you are accessing the site locally, it will show local host. Below code will help you

```
        string clientIp = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
     if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIp) ) 
{
      string[] forwardedIps = clientIp.Split( new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
      clientIp = forwardedIps[forwardedIps.Length - 1];
     } 
else {
      clientIp = context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

`::1`  is a IPv6 loopback address.That means `127.0.0.1`

```
Ipv4  127.0.0.1    localhost
Ipv6  ::1          localhost
```

[localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)