# how to get Ip address in asp.net mvc 4 or mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ip

How to get ip address in asp.net mvc 5?I have tried some solutions like but they are giving result as '::1' only so please suggest .Thanks in advance

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577496/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're doing it right to me.
It will probably only show that IP when running locally

[What is IP address ::1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611418/what-is-ip-address-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IHttpConnectionFeature`

```
var ipAddress = httpContext.GetFeature<IHttpConnectionFeature>().RemoteIpAddress;
```

You can refer [this](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/getting-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-vnext-web-applications) article for complete explanation.