# Strange http end point on local GAE datastore emulator

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I installed datastore emulator in google app engine. After I install the datastore emulator based on the tutorial from https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator. I found

[datastore] API endpoint: http://::1:8862
[datastore]   export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=::1:8862

When I access the endpoint on Safari, it can not be accessed. I think http://::1:8862 is a strange address and I do not know why it happened and how to solve the problem. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That address means `localhost` (in IPv6 format) and port 8862. See [What is IPV6 for localhost and 0.0.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189084/what-is-ipv6-for-localhost-and-0-0-0-0)

I didn't use the emulator, so I'm not sure if this applies to the API endpoint or not: maybe you can specify your desired one using the `--host-port` argument. From  [gcloud beta emulators datastore start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/datastore/start):

> `--host-port=HOST_PORT`
>
> The host:port to which the emulator should be bound. Can take the form
>   of a single address (hostname, IPv4, or IPv6) and port:
>
> ```
>   ADDRESS[:PORT]
> ```
>
> In this format you must enclose IPv6 addresses in square brackets:
>   e.g.
>
> ```
>   [2001:db8:0:0:0:ff00:42:8329]:8080
> ```
>
> The default value is localhost:8081.