# http-proxy-middleware to modify port only

Tags: http-proxy-middleware

I'm using an advanced proxy in [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) which uses http-proxy-middleware. I'd like to pass through the domain and modify the port only for all requests.

I believe in create-react-app I must use the shorthand:

```
app.use(
  '/api',
  proxy({ target: 'http://www.example.org:8000' })
)
```

Is there a way I can pass through all requests to API so that the domain is unchanged but the port is 8000?

Answer (score 2):

I found that this approach works:

const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    proxy('/api', {
      target: 'https://[::1]:8000',
      secure: false,
    })
  )
}
```

As a way to proxy `https://<any-domain>:3000/api` to `https://<any-domain>:8000`, as mentioned in a few issues on the http-proxy-middleware. However, this seems a little hacky, and I can find no reference to this in the docs.

If anyone has any additional feedback on this, I'd be very interested to read more.

Note that `::1` is just the [IPv6 loopback address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189084/what-is-ipv6-for-localhost-and-0-0-0-0).