# Socket Programming in Java using IPv6

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, ipv6

I am new with the network programming and I have a few questions, that I couldn't find anywhere.
I don't understand if there is a difference in code between IPv4 and IPv6, when establishing connection.

Example Code :
`Socket socket = new Socket(“127.0.0.1”, 5000)`

The above code is used for IPv4, as I understood. But how do I initialize the socket if I want to use IPv6?

Comment: Use `"::1"` for `127.0.0.1` in IPv6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand if there is a difference in code between ipv4 and ipv6, when establishing connection.

There is little difference.

- If you want to use an explicit IPv6 address, you will typically just instantiate the `Socket` with a IP address string in [IPv6 syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Representation).
- If you use a DNS name, then the available network stacks will determine whether you use IPv4 or IPv6:

  - If only one stack is supported (by the OS) and available, that is used.
  - If both stacks are available, the setting of the `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` property determines which is used.

For more information, read [Networking IPv6 User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/index.html) from the Oracle Java documentation.

> For example this: `Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000)` is used for ip4, as I understood. But how do I initialize the socket if I want to use ip6?

```
Socket socket = new Socket("::1", 5000);
```

See also: [What is IPV6 for localhost and 0.0.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189084/what-is-ipv6-for-localhost-and-0-0-0-0)

Comment: Situation is simple, if we used ip-numbers
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000) 
Socket socket = new Socket("::1", 5000)

Situation is not that simple if we use hostnames.
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000)
Seems, that we get IPv4 socket, no IPv6 socket, and there is no way to define, that we prefere IPv6.

Comment: @ReijoKorhonen - What is  `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` set to?  How / when is it set?

Comment: preferIPv6Addresses and preferIPv4Addresses are java virtual machine parameters and they can be set like this  java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true ... com.example.MainClass <args>. My problem get IPv6 connection with Socket("localhost", 5000) was solved to use IPv6 IP-number syntax Socket("::1", 5000), meaning that I can't use hostname-syntax, but must get IPv6 ip-address first with ":"-syntax and that is only solution I know that works. Otherwise connect is done with IPv4.

Comment: The other thing to look at is whether your DNS resolver resolves "localhost" to an IPv4 or IPv6 address ... or both.  That will be an OS thing.

Comment: And the other way to get the localhost (loopback!) IP is `InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress()` ... which should be IPv4 or IPv6 per the setting (or otherwise) of `preferIPv4Stack`.