# public ip npm package not working in Digital Ocean server

Tags: node.js

I have used the `public-ip` npm package to get the public IP address of the user, it is giving the same public IP address as in http://whatismyipaddress.com, but when using it in a Digital Ocean server it is giving me the Digital Ocean IP address instead of user's public IP address.

I have tried it on nodejs.

```
const publicIp = require('public-ip');
const ip = await publicIp.v4(); //to save ip in user
```

I want the public IP address of the user instead of getting the Digital Ocean IP address.

Comment: You don't need any module to get user ip. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node

Answer (score 0):

Just query `https://api.ipify.org/`

```js
// web
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.ipify.org');
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status != 200) {
    console.log(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found
  } else { // show the result
    console.log(xhr.response)
  }
};

// nodejs
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://api.ipify.org', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

Comment: nodejs version of the code giving this error -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 4. Can you please see it

Comment: Use function instead of arrow function, also updated the code

Comment: console.log(data) works instead of JSON.parse(data). Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This function `publicIp.v4()` and `public-ip` module will help you get (detect) your public IP of server or computer that application's running on (not IP of user). And Digital Ocean returns value of its public IP is right.

In your case, you need to retrieve user's IP from user's request, it can be call remote client IP address. It's better for you to check this question [Express.js: how to get remote client address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address)

Hope it can help.

Comment: var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress; This is returning ::1, why not ip?

Comment: ::1 is equal localhost in IPv6 (means 127.0.0.1 in IPv4). Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611418/what-is-ip-address-1/4611421

Comment: I am getting ::ffff:127.0.0.1 .How we can change to a ip, we get in whatismyipaddress.com?