# Performance has improved by using express-simple-cdn but get 404-not-found error in console

Tags: express, http-status-code-404, cdn

I have implemented express-simple-cdn in my angular app by mapping the local ip domain in /etc/hosts of my linux OS. The performance has improved from 50 to 80 using chrome lighthouse . However, I get this on hitting the application url on browser-

[image: my project-error]

My code is -

app.js  in angular (as I run my angular app through app.js file)

```
var CDN = "http://myproject.test"

app.locals.CDN = function(path, type, classes, alt) {
    if(type == 'js') {
        return "<script src='"+CDN+path+"' type='text/javascript'></script>";
    } else if (type == 'css') {
        return "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='"+CDN+path+"'/>";
    } else if (type == 'img') {
        return "<img class='"+classes+"' src='"+CDN+path+"' alt='"+alt+"' />";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
};

module.exports = app;
```

index.html

```
 <img class="img-responsive" style = "visibility:hidden" src="http://myproject.test/../../assets/images/insta.BIZ.banner.d.jpg.png" alt="my picture" />
```

even when I change the path to -

```
<img class="img-responsive" style = "visibility:hidden" src="http://myproject.test/assets/images/insta.BIZ.banner.d.jpg.png" alt="my picture" />
```

I still get the same error .Also is it that I am getting false reading because of the error in Lighthouse ?

Comment: "The performance has improved from 50 to 80 using chrome lighthouse ."  That really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to input the value in html in single quotations as -

```
<img class="img-responsive" style = "visibility:hidden" src="'http://myproject.test/assets/images/insta.BIZ.banner.d.jpg.png'" alt="my picture" />
```